# Numpy solver : max value

Tags: python, numpy

I`ve got 2 variables :

*period* and *result*

How would I tell the Numpy solver ( I assume that's what I would have to use ) to return the **period value** that gives me the **highest result** ? Period has to be between 1 and 100 .

*Edit :*

Right now **period** at 14, gives me a **result** of 40 .
**period** at 12 . gives me a **result** of 42 .

Can I tell numpy to try every **period** value between 1 and 100 and result only the one with the best result ?

I guess I don`t really need Numpy for that, I was wondering if it could be a way to go .

Comment: What are you talking about? You want to find out what value for one number yields the highest value for the other. If you already have both numbers, then there isn't a question at all. If one of them is calculated from the other - **what is the formula**?

Comment: sorry, edited the question to be more precise .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a variable equal to the period value of the first, then do your own loop, changing the initial variable any time the current number is bigger:

```
biggest = period(0)
index = 0

for i in range (1, 100)
    if period(i) > biggest
         biggest = period(i)
         index = i

return biggest
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain i understand the question, but if i do then NumPy indexing might be best:

```
period = NP.arange(50)
result = NP.random.randint(1, 101, 50)

q = NP.argmax(result)   # gives index of largest value in the result array
result[q]               # returns the highest value in the result array
period[q]               # returns the value of period corresponding to 
                        # the highest value for result
```

Comment: that looks pretty neat, the simple solution without involving Numpy saved me for now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what data you have, but this should work:

```
for period in periods:
    result = func(period)
    if result > resultmax:
        resultmax = result
```

or, if `results` is a `numpy.array` such that `results[period]` is the result from `period`, then simply

```
periodmax = results.argmax()
```